# Elastic Beanstalk not streaming to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've had an Elastic Beanstalk instance streaming my logs to Cloud Watch for about a year. This week the logs stopped streaming. This may have been because I 'rebuilt' the environment in Beanstalk. No configuration changes were made at the same time.

I've double checked that my Beanstalk role has the correct permissions in IAM (it has CloudWatchFullAccess).

I also tried deleting all of my existing group logs. I then went into the Beanstalk 'Instance log streaming to CloudWatch Logs' area, changed my log retention period and restarted the App Server. Sure enough my log groups were recreated (with the new retention period), so I'm pretty sure the permissions look OK. Despite this, no log messages are appearing in the log groups.

I have requested the recent logs though Beanstalk and I can see messages are being written to the logs on the App Server OK.

My platform is `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.2`

I'm not sure where to go from here. I have no error messages to work off, or any good ideas for what to check next.

Edit: Here is my custom config for CloudWatch, as defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html)

```
files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/company_log.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat8/company.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat8/company.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat8/company.*
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because it's not allowed to. Make sure the role used by the EC2 instances is allowed to access:

```
logs:CreateLogGroup
logs:CreateLogStream
logs:GetLogEvents
logs:PutLogEvents
logs:DescribeLogGroups
logs:DescribeLogStreams
logs:PutRetentionPolicy
```

With Elastic Beanstalk the IAM role used by the EC2 instances is probably `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`. Give that role access to a new policy: `ec2-cloudwatch-logs-stream` (if someone knows a better name let me know) using JSON (as suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.streaming)):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:GetLogEvents",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And it should work after restarting the `awslogs` service with `sudo services awslogs restart`. If not; check the logs. You can find it here: `/var/log/awslogs.log`

Comment: I had to upgrade my EBS instance to the latest OS. The AWS logging agent on that version was no longer compatible with CloudWatch, even though the instance was not very old at all.

Comment: This issue is still happening today if not using the latest "platform" as ElasticBeanstalk refers to as (I guess) it's just AMIs in the back.

I stopped receiving log streams into CloudWatch for some time, with no warning (luckily I was also rotating logs to S3), just upgraded to latest platform called "Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.14.1" and it's streaming the logs again...

Answer (score 0):

You might have upgraded your AWS AMI platform, the Tomcat location is therefore different (e.g. /var/log/tomcat instead of /var/log/tomcat8).

I've detailed in a new [Medium blog](https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-setup-aws-elasticbeanstalk-to-stream-your-custom-application-logs-to-cloudwatch-d5c877eaa242) how this all works and an example .ebextensions file and where to put it.

Below is an excerpt that you might be able to use, though the article explains how to determine the right folder/file(s) to stream.

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 90

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [plugins]
      cwlogs = cwlogs
      [default]
      region = `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}`

  "/etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/localhost.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/localhost.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/catalina.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/catalina.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/catalina.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost_access_log.txt]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/access_log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/access_log.*

commands:
  "01":
    command: systemctl enable awslogsd.service
  "02":
    command: systemctl restart awslogsd
```